# ReportServer Eclipse Edit & Deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, war, reportserver

I am trying to use the fantastic ReportServer BI suite. https://reportserver.net/en/ However I need to edit some of the featues and would like to use Eclipse. However I can not find a way to edit the code, and redistribute it as a war file. I have tried importing the source code of the project to eclipse but it creates many projects instead of a dynamic web project which eclipse uses. Simply put I would like to import ReportServer into eclipse, edit and test within eclipse, then be able to export it as a war. Any insight? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [recent tutorial](https://reportserver.net/en/tutorials/dev-30/) on how to set up ReportServer in Eclipse as part of the official ReportServer documentation. Have a look at the tutorials section (Development) of [the documentation page](https://reportserver.net/en/documentation/).

Following are the basics: Setting up ReportServer in Eclipse is straight forward (some tweaks here and there) if you have worked with GWT before. That said, ReportServer is based on GWT (current ReportServer version 3.0 is based on GWT 2.7), so the first step is to install GWT 2.7 as well as the GWT Eclipse plugin.

Then create a new web application project and copy in the sources (both sources and binaries are available on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dw-rs/). Ensure to also copy the metadata model folder als a source folder. Most of the necessary libraries can be taken from the packaged binaries file (WEB-INF/lib). There are a few binaries missing, in essence this is [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/).

Finally, ensure that the memory settings are sufficient, that is, ReportServer should be at least given one, better two GB RAM. Before starting ReportServer ensure that you have created the necessary database (ddls are provided in the ddl folder of the binaries archive) and configured the database settings (an example is also shipped with the binaries).

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).